# Gazebo Garden Installation Error Ubuntu 20

Tags: gazebo

i am getting multiple 404 errors when installing Gazebo Garden. seems like something to do with the file version, old vs. new (i.e., 5.4.2-1 vs. 5.5.0-1). Error message below. Appreciate any help with this.

```
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable/pool/main/g/gz-common5/libgz-common5-dev_5.4.2-1~focal_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 52.52.171.73 80]
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean run of installing gz-garden seems fine in https://build.osrfoundation.org/job/gz_garden-install-pkg-focal-amd64/162/console, installing `5.5.0-1`. Could you please run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gz-garden` and see if that works?

If the problems persists, could you please include in the description of the problem the result of `apt-cache show libgz-common5-dev`.

Hope if helps.